# How to Load an object to a jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my javascript, I have a function which will return an element present in the HTML page .i have this stored in a variable and now want to do some kind of traversal in that using jquery methods like parent/fadeIn/fadeOut etc.

How can i do that.? My current code which returns the object is

```
 var currentObject= GetThatObject();
```

Now i really want to play with this object like what we do with a typical jQuery object which we get like

```
   var curObj=$("#tatElement")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just do this:

```
var curObj = $(currentObject);
```

jQuery can take not only selector strings but HTML elements as arguments as well. It will just take that element, wrap it in its jQuery object and you can then use it the same way as if you had used a selector string. (It is actually a little more efficient because jQuery doesn't have to parse the selector and find the element).